# Birthdays emails using workflows

Tags: email, workflow, configuration

I want to send email on to users on their birthdays in salesforce using workflows. Is this possible ?

Comment: All you need is to do Time dependent workFlow ,,but here arises a problem ,that you can control this field only once

Answer (score 1):

Workflow rules don't "quite" work that way, so you can't get there 100% without some code; the more appropriate means of doing this is either scheduled apex classes or a combination of triggers and workflow rules.

As a trigger/workflow combo, you simply do the following:

1) Create a field called "next birthday."
2) Create a trigger that populates the field with the next birthday in the future.
3) Create a workflow rule (time dependent) that (a) clears the next birthday field and (b) sends the birthday message. The entry criteria should be "next birthday not equals" (blank). You can specify the number of days before to send the birthday wishes, but remember to adjust the trigger to account for those days when calculating the next birthday.

As a scheduled class, simply have it run daily, calculate who needs a birthday wish, and send one out.

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this by writing a timebased workflow rule which will send email on birthday.
For the workflow entry criteria you can wrrite:
User.Birthdate = Today();

when this criteria is met, it will trigger an email alert.

Comment: That entry criteria won't work.